# Reloading nginx config from within a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx

I have a multi-app system running on a centOS box, that consists of our main app and a deployer app. when a client wants a new instance of our app, they use our deployer, fill in some info and the new install is created on our server. the issue i am having is that i can't get nginx to reload it's config file automatically. so after the deploy when visiting the new app we receive a 404 until i reload manually.

I've tried a few different ways including chmod /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx to 777, chmod the install script and deployer app to 777,

the script goes like this:

```
#create install directory -- works correctly
#copy files over -- works correctly
#run install script
##-- and then at this point i've tried multiple lines, including:
system("nginx -s reload") ## this works manually
system("/etc/init.d/nginx reload") ## this works manually
```

### i've followed directions here: [Restart nginx without sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011067/restart-nginx-without-sudo) to create a script to run without a sudo password and then tried this:

```
system("sudo /var/www/vhosts/deployer/lib/nginx_reload")
```

nothing seems to work, i'm assuming this is a permissions error, but maybe i'm wrong, if anyone could point me in any direction, that would be very helpful since i've been trying to figure this out for a few days too long and i'm fresh out of new ideas

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, i figured it out, our server had a mess of permissions, nginx ran as a different user than passenger which ran as a different user than the deployer which ran as a different user than the app, after playing around a little longer i've gotten it to work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sudo  /etc/init.d/nginx reload`